# Can I change the label's font size on line chart react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to make the labels bigger in react react-native-chart-kit, is it possible?

Comment: Have you try use ```labelStyle``` prop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use propsForLabels to override styles of labels.

https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit